# Reading javascript variables from external website in C# program

Tags: javascript, c#

I'd like to ask how can you read JS vars and pass them to a C# program?

I am trying to read the var from external website (something like chrome debugger that prints out the var in the console  but i need to process the var in c#). I've heard something about ASP.NET but I don't think that's going to work for my case.

Comment: You'd need some code which can download the contents of the web page, work out which part is JavaScript, parse the JavaScript and extract the data. Such a thing may well exist already if you search (in the field of web scraping), it would be tricky to build it yourself though (the JavaScript parsing would be the tricky bit, unless you have a good idea of the structure in advance, and the structure isn't too complicated, so you could maybe use some regular expressions to find the relevant bit).

Answer (score -1):

In general when you want to solve a problem by written a program, you need to know

1. what is the input
2. what will be the expected output

For 1. you have a js variable such as `var input = { /* some object */ }`
Let's assuming that 2. is print it out in the C# program.

So, how to connecting 1. and 2.? This is what you may want to do: **sending the js variable (i.e. the data in a frontend) to a C# server (the backend).**

If what I stated is the problem you want to solve, you build the **C# backend by .NET Core** (ASP.NET is also a option but I mention .NET Core here because I am not sure which platform your C# program will run, and .NET Core is cross-platform).

If the js variables you want to send is **on a webpage that also controlled by you**, what you need to do is sending those js variables from frontend to backend by making a HTTP call, such as a *form POST*.

**In other words, you need to build a website running .NET Core which allows you to send data from a frontend built by HTML, CSS and JS.**

To build a .NET Core server, you can take a look on this this article: [Creating the simplest possible ASP.NET Core form with a POST method](https://dev.to/azure/creating-the-simplest-possible-aspnet-core-form-with-a-post-method-416g).

Comment: The question clearly says "**external** website". So none of this answer is relevant